# How to disable Ctrl+Backspace in text fields on Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

Title. Any means as long as it's Windows only and no third-party programs. So regedit/gpedit/etc all available.

Edit: Specifically trying to disable Ctrl+Backspace when text is highlighted. As it doesn't actually delete the highlighted text. Sometimes I end up having to Ctrl+A and then attempt to backspace several times before I can actually delete it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which applications are concerned? Many apps implement their own text-handling.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried, and what application(s) does this need to be functional in?

Comment: @harrymc, All applications are concerned. Ctrl+Backspace in any field with selected text.

Comment: @music2myear I've extensively searched Google and other Stack sites for this problem, have not found anything even with disabling control shortcuts even come up. I've seen some for Win key shortcuts but not control. And again, all applications. I want to disable Ctrl+Backspace system-wide.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following one-liner script will disable
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> in all of Windows:

```
^Backspace::Return
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

The above script can be improved to act only for specific programs
by adding to it one or more
[#IfWinActive](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm)
directives.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: "Any means as long as it's Windows only and no third-party programs." AHK is a third party program so this doesn't help.

Comment: There is no solution except by using a third-party product. The Windows registry allows disabling Ctrl or Backspace, but not the combination of both. Try one of the best tools for mapping/disabling keys via the registry and see: [SharpKeys](https://www.randyrants.com/category/sharpkeys/).